# Gradle buildTypes incompatible types

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Gradle build tool. I want to create constant OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY in android app but I am getting following error

[image: error message]

build.gradle

```
  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine.app"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }

        }

        buildTypes.all { variant ->
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", "1"
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    }`
```

I tried multiple things but can not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
variant.buildConfigField "String", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", "1"
```

with:

```
variant.buildConfigField "String", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", '"1"'
```

The `String` needs to be quoted. If the field was an `int`, you could have left it unquoted.